# i18n Polish characters issue

Tags: c#, internationalization, asp.net-mvc-4, translation, polish

I have a web application in mvc4 with i18n internalization using:

https://github.com/danielcrenna/i18n#readme

Everyting works fine until i start to addnig Polish characters like : ś, ź, ć etc.

the characters are replaced by : � marks.

and when running the args of xgettext.exe are set to:

`var args = string.Format("-LC# -k_ --omit-header --from-code=UTF-8 -o\"{0}\\locale\\messages.pot\" -f\"{1}\"", path, manifest);`

Have somebody any idea?

Comment: Turns out that "smart Internationalization" is not so smart. Any particular reasons, why you cannot use built-in mechanism for I18n and trying to use some wheel re-inventing thing? By the way, "based on i18n best practices" sounds like a huge joke for me.

Comment: i know that it isn't standard way for translations in .net aplication but i'm using this because i need to have the same translations for a lot of platform(web, desktop, phone etc)by *.po files, and standard *.resx file don't give that abillity.

Comment: Got it, makes sense. I suspect there is some issue with the library you want to use. At the moment the only (ugly) workaround which may possibly work for you, would be to write Polish diacritics as HTML entities, i.e. `&#F3;`. However, that would be terrible from the translator's point of view and not necessary universal, i.e. phone and desktop may work incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking about some wrapper like this because when you pass numericall code of a letter it work, but it's a final solution if i don't find anything else, now i'm investigating this i18n problem (i hope the bug will be there) i will write if i find something. Anyway thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try including the following tag in the HTML of your documents.

I've seen the question marks pop up when trying to display pure hex from a wrong starting position in a char array in C.  The browser probably doesn't know what to do with the char hex it is given.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```